# How to add the package into Java?

Tags: java

I was running a Java code online, but there is an error for the java code. The error line is:

```
package binary.ga;
```

The error information for this line is `"the declared package "binary.ga" does not match the expected package"`. Can anybody help me fix the problem?

Comment: is your java class in that package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally that means that the `.java` file is not in the correct folder.  Your folder structure should look like:

```
binary/
   ga/
      MyClass.java
```

Comment: My situation is: C:\eclipse-java-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\workspace\GeneticAlgorithm\src\BinaryGA.java. How to modify the package?

Comment: You can either remove the package declaration from the code, or you can create the folder structure for the .java file to live in under /src.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to replace this line with correct package, for example my project structure looks like this:

[image]

so package for Content class is net.elenx

Comment: My situation is: C:\eclipse-java-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\workspace\GeneticAlgorithm\src\BinaryGA.java. How to modify the package?

Comment: you should create new java project in Eclipse. Package is usually you company name with reversed notation, in project creator you can define you package name, type whatever you want or leave standard value, then just place your code in this package